# Use of can't even or even can't

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

I saw a question while going through spotting error exercise.([See question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vT4jv0TSxQT8fVdxA_VgcEPsAWq_BlwL/view?usp=drivesdk)) Book says to replace *even can't* with *can't even*.

- He has been going to office/ for a year now and/ he **even can't** understand its working/No error.

But even can't is also correct???

Comment: This question shows no research and no effort. Pleaee explain what research you did before posting your question and why you believe there is only one right answer.

Comment: I have learnt a phrase 'can't even', but i encounter sentence with 'even can't'. So it is my query whether both are correct or not

Comment: On this site if you want good answers, you need to show the research and the effort. No research, no effort, your questions will either be ignored or closed by the community.

Comment: This is what I mean by research: 1. https://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/even.html and 2. http://theamericanreader.com/life-sentences-the-abcs-of-i-cant-even/ and 3. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can-t-even-begin. If you're still confused add the explanation(s) that doesn't answer your query and explain why.